# Как правильно вывести произвольный список именованных аргументов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, format

Напишите функцию, принимающую сведения об авторе (в виде произвольного
списка именованных аргументов) и выводящая их на экран в указанном
формате:
И.О.Фамилия (дата рождения - дата смерти) - краткая информация

```
    def creator( sep = '.', **kwargs):
        return kwargs['name'][0]

    print(creator(name = 'Lev', patr = 'Nikolaevich', surname = 'Tolstoi',birth = 
    '09.09.1828', death = '20.11.1920', krt = 'Russian author'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это с помощью [строк формата](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).

***Пример:***

```py
def creator(sep='.', **kwargs):
    n = kwargs['name'][0]
    p = kwargs['patr'][0]
    surname = kwargs['surname']
    birth = kwargs['birth']
    death = kwargs['death']
    krt = kwargs['krt']

    return f'{n}{sep}{p}{sep}{surname} ({birth} - {death}) - {krt}'

print(creator(name='Lev', patr='Nikolaevich', surname='Tolstoi', birth='09.09.1828', death='20.11.1920', krt='Russian author'))
```

***stdout:***

```py
L.N.Tolstoi (09.09.1828 - 20.11.1920) - Russian author
```

Answer (score 3):

Пример через метод `str.format`:

```
def creator(sep='.', **kwargs) -> str:
    return '{name[0]}{sep}{patr[0]}{sep}{surname} ({birth} - {death}) - {krt}'.format(**kwargs, sep=sep)


print(creator(
    name='Lev', patr='Nikolaevich', surname='Tolstoi', 
    birth='09.09.1828', death='20.11.1920', krt='Russian author'
))
# L.N.Tolstoi (09.09.1828 - 20.11.1920) - Russian author
```